# Disable the date after select in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I am facing a problem to disable the date on datepicker after select any date.

**My HTML Markup :**

```
Day 1 <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" /> <br/>
Day 2 <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" />  <br/>
Day 3 <input type="text" id="datepicker3" name="datepicker3" /><br/>
Day 4 <input type="text" id="datepicker4" name="datepicker4" /><br/>
Day 5 <input type="text" id="datepicker5" name="datepicker5" /><br/>
Day 6 <input type="text" id="datepicker6" name="datepicker6" /><br/>
Day 7 <input type="text" id="datepicker7" name="datepicker7" /><br/>
```

**JavaScript Which i used :**

```
var dates = $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6, #datepicker7").datepicker({
    minDate: "0",
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(date) {
        for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; ++i) {
            if(dates[i].id < this.id)
                $(dates[i]).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
            else if(dates[i].id > this.id)
                $(dates[i]).datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
        }
    } 
});
```

**[My JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tipstolearn/tfqyakn2/)**

I got that [**useful script**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/h3wGx/4/) on JsFiddle. There date disabling properly after select 1 date. But i need to use that for 7 date. So anyone help me to use that useful script for me in my jsfiddle example!

**## I want date will be just disable after select. It will be unavailable to select next.**

Comment: I think I completely misunderstood your intent with this question. You want the date itself to no longer be available in your datepicker, not the input fields to be disabled. I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Yes... Any help for me in your next answer plz?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/h3wGx/4/ there it working porperly but i cant add 7 date there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are a different version where the dates are not available when it is selected in the input fields, http://jsfiddle.net/tfqyakn2/6/

```
var datesMin = [];
var dates = $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6, #datepicker7").datepicker({
minDate: "+0",
maxDate: "+2Y",
defaultDate: "+1w",
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
numberOfMonths: 1,
onSelect: function(date) {               
    datesMin.push( new Date( $(this).val() ) );         
},
beforeShow: function() {        
    $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", maxi());
 }   
});

function sortDates(a, b){
return a.getTime() - b.getTime();
}   

function maxi(){ 
var sorted = datesMin.sort(sortDates);    
var minDate;
if(datesMin.length > 0){
minDate = sorted[sorted.length-1];    
} else {
minDate = 0;    
}
return minDate;
}
```

Comment: http://s5.postimg.org/60cl5vxbb/freelancingcare_2014_09_17.jpg Look that bro.. there still i can add same date there :(
I want user cant add same date again 
and again.
Please look that http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/h3wGx/4/ jsfiddle there you cant select same day. I want this similar way in my script.

Comment: Well if you had that one you could do it yourself, it was just one +1 to add. Here it is updated and upvote the answer http://jsfiddle.net/tfqyakn2/8/

Answer (score 0):

As I Understood you want to disable a date that you select on the datefields, and that date should not be available to the rest of the input fields(datepickers).

I've made some changes to your script:
http://jsfiddle.net/tfqyakn2/5/

I believe that this is the answer you are looking for.

```
var disabledDates = [];

var dates = $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6, #datepicker7").datepicker({
    minDate: "0",
    maxDate: "+2Y",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(date) {        
        disabledDates.push($(this).val());        
    },
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
});

function unavailable(date) {
    dateZero = ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
             + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
             + date.getFullYear();    
    if ($.inArray(dateZero, disabledDates) < 0) {
        return [true,"","Available Date"];
    } else {
        return [false,"","Not Available Date"];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you kind answer. There have a little issue.. I hope you will help to fix that.
When i am selecting the future date in Day 1 then past date still available to select in Day 2 or other.. It should be disable too..

Check that plz : http://s5.postimg.org/gjckv1zzb/freelancingcare_2014_09_17.jpg

Comment: I appreciate your help for me..plz check my comment on your 2nd answer. I am writing it again here "
 
s5.postimg.org/60cl5vxbb/freelancingcare_2014_09_17.jpg Look that bro.. there still i can add same date there :( I want user cant add same date again and again. Please look that jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/h3wGx/4 jsfiddle there you cant select same day. I want this similar way in my script."